# how to remove this faucet stem?

Tags: faucet, bathtub

I got this old place recently and the tub faucet has been leaking like crazy. I tried google videos and can't find anything on how to remove this type of faucet/stem. I don't see any hex nut to remove it and the black part is just a washer.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Here is [the picture](https://photos.app.goo.gl/5Z5CMRHTvy1V14f5A).

Comment: Can you post some more detailed photos that show clearly the areas between the outside threading and the tile? I think you may need to put a rag over the threads to protect them, then use slip joint pliers to carefully unscrew the threaded part counter clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the stem counter clockwise.

It looks as if that is ready to come out, if it would be turned. Those stems don't slide out like cartridges.

Comment: You certainly need to first turn the stem fully "on" (after turning off the water supply!) I'm not sure that turning the stem further will remove the whole valve though.